# I am trying to install "pytesseract" but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to install "pytesseract" but the code after that doesn't work

```
  
from PIL import Image

from pytesseract import pytesseract

#Define path to tessaract.exe
path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Python310\Scripts\pytesseract.exe'

#Define path to image
path_to_image = 'extract.png'

#Point tessaract_cmd to tessaract.exe
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

#Open image with PIL
img = Image.open(path_to_image)

#Extract text from image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

when run the code it shows this error
(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract')

Comment: Either you are not installing it to the same environment that you are running your scripts in, or your are not installing it correctly.

Comment: pytesseract installed in c:\python\script

Comment: But _how_ did you install it? Typically people don't install Python modules to specific folders, as it's usually done automatically. Did you use the command `pip install pytesseract` to install it, as the [official instructions](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) say to do? Also, did you install the prerequisites that are listed on that page?

Comment: yes I used Command line and it's installed automatically in the folder that I mentioned it

Comment: I assumed you used the command line. But you didn't mention what command you used. You didn't answer my question about installing the prerequisites, or verifying that you are running the code in the same environment you're installing modules to. If you are going to continue to ignore my questions and advice, then I can't help you.